# How to use FindEelementById in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to open the google chrome and search "Christmas date" using excel VBA. The code I am using:

```
Sub test544()

  Dim chromePath As String

  chromePath = """C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""

 Shell (chromePath & " -url chrome-extension://dehlblnjjkkbapjemjbeafjhjpjoifii/index.html")

End Sub
```

It opens chrome. Now I am trying to search "Christmas Date" on chrome by FindElementById and SendKeys as follows:

```
   chromePath.FindElementById("keywords").SendKeys ("Christmas date")
     chromePath.FindElementById("Button").Click
```

Which shows the following error

[image]

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You are using Selenium Basic syntax without referencing the Selenium Basic library and instancing the webdriver to automate the browser. This will therefore fail.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this :

```
 chromePath.FindElementById("keywords").SendKeys ("Christmas date")
 chromePath.FindElementById("Button").Click
```

do this :

```
 chromePath.FindElementById("keywords").SendKeys "Christmas date"
 chromePath.FindElementById("Button").Click
```

Is `button` a unique identifier in your application ?

**Update 1 :**

```
Dim bot As New WebDriver
bot.Start "chrome", "http://google.com"
```

Comment: Yes. Still the same error of    "chromePath Invalid qualifier"

Comment: I would start my driver like this : `Dim bot As New WebDriver
bot.Start "chrome", "http://google.com"`

Comment: Yes this method works for me as well. But the issue is that every time it opens a new chrome window and there is no previous chrome history, and I have to add chrome extension and login in chrome  extension manually every time

Comment: What is your scenario ? Do you really need chrome extension ?

Comment: I am opening extension using this code. But every time I have to manually click on popup button to add extension using this code as below:'                                      
`Dim obj As New WebDriver
Dim i As Integer
obj.Start "chrome", ""
obj.Get " https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amazon-kw-index-and-rank/dehlblnjjkkbapjemjbeafjhjpjoifii?hl=en"
obj.Wait 3000

obj.FindElementByClass("webstore-test-button-label").Click

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

obj.Get ("chrome-extension://dehlblnjjkkbapjemjbeafjhjpjoifii/index.html")`

Comment: you need to create a profile and launch that profile via settings for webdriver. I will dig out an old answer to this if I can find it. I don't think you have access to history however.